# How to remove specific draggable element from a div by it's id?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

So I want to remove a certain draggable element based on its id from a specific div too. So if I have 2 of the same elements in 1 div, I wanna remove only from it.

Element's id: drag1 
Div's class name: b1

Javascript:

```
$("#drag1").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
 });

$(".b1").droppable({
     drop: function (event, ui) {
});

if ($("#suc").attr("src") === img2) {
     //remove one of the draggable drag1 from a div
       if ($("#drag1, #drag1", $(".b1")).length === 2) {
              $("#drag1").remove();
            }
        }
```

I tried the .remove() method but it removes from the original position instead of the div.

Comment: use its ID ID should be unique so it is only one

Comment: use .detach() and check

Comment: using detach(), when i click on the button once, it still removes from the original position, and when i click twice, it does removes one from the div itself.. i only want it to remove from the div itself